# After a Plone 2.5x to Plone 3.x migration, how do I correct the kss_generic_macros problem?

Tags: plone, plone-3.x

I get the error below on several views. Which seems identical to what is described here in this [other kss_generic_macros](http://plone.org/support/forums/general#nabble-td336363) post. An answer is supplied, which is "*This was caused by the 2.5->3.0 migration process failing to add the plone_kss layer to a handful of our custom skins. When I went in and added plone_kss by hand to those skins, it fixed this.*"

This is only so helpful. A code sample or a real pointer as to where you add plone_kss would make this much easier to solve.

```
2009-06-24 15:24:28 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1245871468.060.103936823493 https://nasascience.on.my.mac/humanator-folder/what-is-six-plus-3/base_view
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 119, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 88, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 42, in call_object
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 313, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 350, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 216, in _exec
  Module Products.CacheSetup.patch_cmf, line 29, in FSPT_pt_render
  Module Products.CacheSetup.patch_utils, line 9, in call_pattern
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 155, in pt_render
  Module Products.CacheSetup.patch_cmf, line 77, in PT_pt_render
  Module Products.CacheSetup.patch_utils, line 9, in call_pattern
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 98, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 117, in pt_render
   - Warning: Macro expansion failed
   - Warning: exceptions.KeyError: 'macro'
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 891, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 525, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 957, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 861, in do_defineMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 957, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 525, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 949, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 861, in do_defineMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 891, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 536, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 521, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 516, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 346, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 870, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: file:/Users/danny/projects/schwa/2.1.0a/trunk/eggs/Products.Archetypes-1.5.10-py2.4.egg/Products/Archetypes/skins/archetypes/base.pt
   - Line 22, Column 10
   - Expression: <PathExpr standard:u'here/kss_generic_macros/macros/generic_title_view'>
   - Names:
      {'container': <PloneSite at /msrd>,
       'context': <Humanatorquestion at /msrd/humanator-folder/what-is-six-plus-3>,
       'default': <object object at 0x1bf528>,
       'here': <Humanatorquestion at /msrd/humanator-folder/what-is-six-plus-3>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {'args': ()},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x9ea75f8>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=https://nasascience.on.my.mac/humanator-folder/what-is-six-plus-3/base_view>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <FSPageTemplate at /msrd/base_view used for /msrd/humanator-folder/what-is-six-plus-3>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <PloneUser 'admin'>}
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 155, in _eval
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 124, in _eval
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 82, in boboAwareZopeTraverse
  Module OFS.Traversable, line 301, in restrictedTraverse
  Module OFS.Traversable, line 269, in unrestrictedTraverse
   - __traceback_info__: ([], 'kss_generic_macros')
AttributeError: kss_generic_macros
```

Comment: Not really a Python issue, though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log into the ZMI then go to the portal_skins tool.  Now click on the "properties" tab.  The "Plone Default" skin should look something like this:

```
custom
cmfeditions_views
CMFEditions
ChangeSet
kupu_plone
kupu
kupu_tests
archetypes
archetypes_kss
mimetypes_icons
plone_kss
ATContentTypes
ATReferenceBrowserWidget
ResourceRegistries
PasswordReset
gruf
plone_ecmascript
plone_wysiwyg
plone_prefs
plone_portlets
plone_templates
plone_styles
plone_form_scripts
plone_scripts
plone_forms
plone_images
plone_content
plone_login
plone_deprecated
plone_3rdParty
cmf_legacy
```

If you are missing any of those you'll need to add them in.  That should solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `plone_kss` layer in your skins. Go to the ZMI (via site setup or by adding /manage to your Plone homepage), find the portal_skins tool, and check your skin layers in the properties tab. Make sure the `plone_kss` layer is listed before the custom layer and you should be set to go.

In future, you can use a command line tool like find to locate missing skin methods; I found this one in a buildout by using the following command:

```
$ find parts/plone -name kss_generic_macros.*
parts/plone/CMFPlone/skins/plone_kss/kss_generic_macros.pt
```

You can automate this with the following Python Script:

```
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName
layer = 'plone_kss'
skins = getToolByName(context, 'portal_skins')
for name in skins.getSkinSelections():
    path = skins.getSkinPath(name)
    path = [i.strip() for i in path.split(',')]
    if layer not in path:
        try:
            path.insert(path.index('custom') + 1, layer)
        except ValueError:
            path.append(layer)
        skins.addSkinSelection(name, ','.join(path))
```

This script loops over all skins in the skins tool, and will insert `plone_kss` into any one of them where it is missing; either just after the `custom` layer, or at the end if there is no `custom` layer present.

The reason you want your `custom` layer to be first is that this layer by custom (no pun intended) holds customized versions of skin assets. If you were to customize an asset from the `portal_kss` layer through the ZMI then the customized version will be put in the `custom` layer. Because skin lookup rules will look through the layer stack top-to-bottom, you want to make sure your customized versions in the `custom` layer are found before the originals in the lower layers.

Comment: Martijn, when I tried out your solution, adding plone_kss worked either before or after custom.

Comment: putting it before custom will of course work, but breaks the convention that customized versions go in the custom layer to override the original. By putting layers higher up, you give their contents a higher precedence, and this is why the `custom` should preferably be the first.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an explanation as to why the custom layer must be kept on top.

Comment: An old answer, but I have a legacy application with exactly this problem. Thanks for helping!